# Multiple Linear Regression function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regression

I have developed Simple Linear regression function in SQL Server from here (https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/96778/can-this-linear-regression-algorithm-for-sql-serve.html) to calculate Alpha,Beta and some extra values like Upper 95% and Lower 95%.
The Simple Linear regression takes the argument as X and y.

Now I am in need of perform Multiple Linear regression SQL Server, which takes arguments y and X1,X2,X3,.....Xn

Hence the Output will be as follows:

```
    Coefficients    Standard Error    t Stat         P-value        Lower 95%     Upper 95%
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    Intercept       -23.94650812     19.85250194     -1.20622117    0.351059563 -109.3649298    
    X Variable 1    0.201064291      0.119759437     1.678901439    0.235179    -0.314218977    
    X Variable 2    -0.014046021     0.037366638     -0.375897368   0.743119791 -0.174821687
    X Variable 3    0.502074905      0.295848189     1.697069389    0.231776287 -0.770857111
    X Variable 4    0.068238344      0.219256527     0.311226057    0.785072958 -0.875146351
```

Anyone can please suggest me a good way to achieve this.

Comment: will you elaborate more by some sample data ?what input you pass and output you expecting .?Thanks

Comment: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/96778/can-this-linear-regression-algorithm-for-sql-serve.html

Comment: Your link explains how these are calculated per attribute, or some external key to each dataset. I think what may be eluding us here, both mathematically (advanced) and set-wise is: what is the significance of X1,...Xn in relation to each dataset?

Comment: I agree with @JaazCole ,clearly state that how the input appear in the form of y and X1,X2,X3,.....Xn.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I am not clear on how to implement it. Can you please give me a suggestion about it

Answer (score 8):

I would look at using [CLR integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) to take advantage of an existing .NET library supporting Linear Regression, for example [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/docs/Regression.html). Using a CLR stored procedure you would be able to read the data out of a table, transform it to the .NET libraries matrix type, run the regression, then either write the results back to a table or return a row set directly.

But just for fun here is [Linear Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) solved via [Orthogonal Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods) using [Householder reflections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_Householder_reflections) in SQL. (Warning will run slowly on any significant amount of data.)

```
-- Create a type to repsent a 2D Matrix

CREATE TYPE dbo.Matrix AS TABLE (i int, j int, Aij float, PRIMARY KEY (i, j))
GO

-- Function to perform QR factorisation ie A -> QR

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.QRDecomposition (
    @matrix dbo.Matrix READONLY
)
RETURNS @result TABLE (matrix char(1), i int, j int, Aij float)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @m int, @n int, @i int, @j int, @a float

    SELECT @m = MAX(i), @n = MAX(j)
    FROM @matrix

    SET @i = 1
    SET @j = 1

    DECLARE @R dbo.Matrix
    DECLARE @Qj dbo.Matrix
    DECLARE @Q dbo.Matrix

    -- Generate a @m by @m Identity Matrix to transform to Q, add more numbers for m > 1000 
    ;WITH e1(n) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    ),
    e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b),
    e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2),
    numbers(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3)
    INSERT INTO @Q (i, j, Aij)
    SELECT i.n, j.n, CASE WHEN i.n = j.n THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM numbers i
    CROSS JOIN numbers j
    WHERE i.n <= @m AND j.n <= @m 

    -- Copy input matrix to be transformed to R
    INSERT @R (i, j, Aij)
    SELECT i, j, Aij
    FROM @matrix

    -- Loop performing Householder reflections
    WHILE @j < @n OR (@j = @n AND @m > @n)  BEGIN

        SELECT @a = SQRT(SUM(Aij * Aij))
        FROM @R
        WHERE j = @j
            AND i >= @i

        SELECT @a = -SIGN(Aij) * @a
        FROM @R
        WHERE j = @j AND i = @j + (@j - 1)

        ;WITH u (i, j, Aij) AS (
            SELECT i, 1, u.ui
            FROM (
                SELECT i, CASE WHEN i = j THEN Aij + @a ELSE Aij END AS ui
                FROM @R
                WHERE j = @j
                    AND i >= @i
            ) u
        )
        INSERT @Qj (i, j, Aij)
        SELECT i, j, CASE WHEN i = j THEN 1 - 2 * Aij ELSE - 2 * Aij END as Aij
        FROM (
            SELECT u.i, ut.i AS j, u.Aij * ut.Aij / (SELECT SUM(Aij * Aij) FROM u) AS Aij
            FROM u u
            CROSS JOIN u ut
        ) vvt

        -- Apply inverse Householder reflection to Q
        UPDATE Qj
            SET Aij = [Qj+1].Aij
        FROM @Q Qj
        INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT Q.i, QjT.j, SUM(QjT.Aij * Q.Aij) AS Aij
            FROM @Q Q
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT i AS j, j AS i, Aij
                FROM @Qj
            ) QjT ON QjT.i = Q.j 
            GROUP BY Q.i, QjT.j
        ) [Qj+1] ON [Qj+1].i = Qj.i AND [Qj+1].j = Qj.j

        -- Apply Householder reflections to R
        UPDATE Rj
            SET Aij = [Rj+1].Aij
        FROM @R Rj
        INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT Qj.i, R.j, SUM(Qj.Aij * R.Aij) AS Aij
            FROM @Qj Qj
            INNER JOIN @R R ON R.i = Qj.j 
            GROUP BY Qj.i, R.j
        ) [Rj+1] ON [Rj+1].i = Rj.i AND [Rj+1].j = Rj.j

        -- Prepare Qj for next Householder reflection
        UPDATE @Qj
            SET Aij = CASE WHEN i = j THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        WHERE i <= @j OR j <= @j

        DELETE FROM @Qj WHERE i > @j AND j > @j

        SET @j = @j + 1
        SET @i = @i + 1

    END

    -- Output Q
    INSERT @result (matrix, i, j, Aij)
    SELECT 'Q', i, j, Aij
    FROM @Q

    -- Output R
    INSERT @result (matrix, i, j, Aij)
    SELECT 'R', i, j, Aij
    FROM @R

    RETURN

END 
GO

-- Function to perform linear regression

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MatrixLeastSquareRegression (
    @X dbo.Matrix READONLY
    , @y dbo.Matrix READONLY
)
RETURNS @b TABLE (i int, j int, Aij float)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @QR TABLE (matrix char(1), i int, j int, Aij float)

    INSERT @QR(matrix, i, j, Aij)
    SELECT matrix, i, j, Aij
    FROM dbo.QRDecomposition(@X)

    DECLARE @Qty dbo.Matrix

    -- @Qty = Q'y
    INSERT INTO @Qty(i, j, Aij)
    SELECT a.j, b.j, SUM(a.Aij * b.Aij)
    FROM @QR a
    INNER JOIN @y b ON b.i = a.i
    WHERE a.matrix = 'Q'
    GROUP BY a.j, b.j

    DECLARE @m int, @n int, @i int, @j int, @a float

    SELECT @m = MAX(j)
    FROM @QR R
    WHERE R.matrix = 'R'

    SET @i = @m

    -- Solve Rb = Q'y via back substitution

    WHILE @i > 0 BEGIN

        INSERT @b (i, j, Aij)
        SELECT R.i, 1, ( y.Aij - ISNULL(sumKnown.Aij, 0) ) / R.Aij
        FROM @QR R
        INNER JOIN @Qty y ON y.i = R.i
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(R.Aij * ISNULL(b.Aij, 0)) AS Aij
            FROM @QR R
            INNER JOIN @b b ON b.i = R.j
            WHERE R.matrix = 'R' 
                AND R.i = @i
        ) sumKnown ON 1 = 1
        WHERE R.matrix = 'R' 
            AND R.i = @i
            AND R.j = @i

        SET @i = @i - 1

    END

    RETURN

END 
GO
```

Here is a test script/example of usage:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (i int IDENTITY(1, 1), X1 float, X2 float, X3 float, X4 float, y float)

DECLARE @c float
DECLARE @b1 float
DECLARE @b2 float
DECLARE @b3 float
DECLARE @b4 float

-- bs are the target coefficiants

SET @c = RAND()
SET @b1 = 2 * RAND()
SET @b2 = 3 * RAND()
SET @b3 = 4 * RAND()
SET @b4 = 5 * RAND()

-- Generate some test data, calcualte y from c + Xb plus some noise: y = c + Xb + e
-- Note: Using RAND() for e is not nomrally ditributed noise as linear regression assumes, this will mess with the estimate of c

DECLARE @k int = 1

WHILE @k < 50 BEGIN

    INSERT @TestData(X1, X2, X3, X4, y)
    SELECT x1, x2, x3, x4, @c + x1 * @b1 + x2 * @b2 + x3 * @b3 + x4 * @b4 + 0.2 * RAND()
    FROM (
        SELECT RAND() AS x1, RAND() AS x2, RAND() AS x3, RAND() AS x4
    ) X

    SET @k = @k + 1

END

-- Put our data into dbo.Matrix types

DECLARE @X dbo.Matrix

INSERT @X (i, j, Aij)
-- Extra column for constant
SELECT i, 1, 1
FROM @TestData
UNION
SELECT i, 2, X1
FROM @TestData
UNION
SELECT i, 3, X2
FROM @TestData
UNION
SELECT i, 4, X3
FROM @TestData
UNION
SELECT i, 5, X4
FROM @TestData

DECLARE @y dbo.Matrix

INSERT @y (i, j, Aij)
SELECT i, 1, y
FROM @TestData

-- Estimates for coefficient values
DECLARE @bhat dbo.Matrix

INSERT @bhat (i, j, Aij)
SELECT i, j, Aij
FROM dbo.MatrixLeastSquareRegression(@X, @y)

SELECT CASE i
        WHEN 1 THEN @c
        WHEN 2 THEN @b1
        WHEN 3 THEN @b2
        WHEN 4 THEN @b3
        WHEN 5 THEN @b4
    END AS b
    , Aij AS best 
FROM @bhat

SELECT y.Aij AS y, Xb.Aij AS yest
FROM (
    SELECT x.i, SUM(x.Aij * bh.Aij) AS Aij
    FROM @X x
    INNER JOIN @bhat bh ON bh.i = x.j
    GROUP BY x.i
) Xb
INNER JOIN @y y ON y.i = Xb.i

SELECT SUM(SQUARE(y.Aij - Xb.Aij)) / COUNT(*) AS [Variance] 
FROM (
    SELECT x.i, SUM(x.Aij * bh.Aij) AS Aij
    FROM @X x
    INNER JOIN @bhat bh ON bh.i = x.j
    GROUP BY x.i
) Xb
INNER JOIN @y y ON y.i = Xb.i
```

Comment: Agree 100%. Some problems are just not suited for SQL. This is definitely one of them. As an alternative to using CLR, I would suggest simply writing a small application in your language of choice. I would recommend a statistical language like [R](http://www.r-project.org/), which has a multitude of regression functionality built-in - also it is easy to connect to SQL data (both for reading and writing), and best of all: It's free!

Comment: Can you expand your solution to get R2 and p-values as well?

Answer (score 1):

While I applaud the effort of writing pure SQL functions that can perform all sorts of advanced statistical calculations, SQL is simply not the best language to solve these kinds of problems in.

CLR is definitely an option (as suggested by David Manning), and compared to pure SQL, it will most likely perform much better with this particular problem.

A different route is to use a statistical language. I would recommend [R](http://www.r-project.org/). It has built-in packages for reading and writing data to SQL Server, and a multitude of functions for performing all kinds of regression. Best of all: It's free! [Here is an excellent introductory article](http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2011/12/statistical-analysis-with-r-and.html) to getting started with R and performing statistical analysis on data from SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [LinearRegression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645871.aspx) DataMining Algorithm from Analysis Services ((though it is naturally a descision tree adapted to linear regression)? You just need to design correct a mining [Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645754.aspx) for it.

HINT: no OLAP cube is needed, you can design it from relational tables/views

Analysis Services functionaly is included in Standard Edition of SQL Server and higher
After processing the model you can [query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645906.aspx) it with SQL-like language and retrieve regression function, variance and other useful things.